# rhel + dmesg + Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, kernel, dmesg

we installed some new VM machines with rhel 7.6

but from dmesg we found the following errors

```
[14706.075255] sd 1:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 1080s
[14706.075370] sd 1:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 1080s
[14706.075881] sd 1:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 1080s


[14706.076007] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-2, logical block 19736964, lost async page write
[14706.076081] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-2, logical block 1268620, lost async page write
[14706.076128] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-2, logical block 19736968, lost async page write
[14706.076172] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-2, logical block 19736966, lost async page write
[14706.076909] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-2, logical block 19736967, lost async page write
[14706.077721] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-2, logical block 19736969, lost async page write
[14706.077760] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-2, logical block 1268621, lost async page write
[14706.077775] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-2, logical block 19736972, lost async page write
[14706.077936] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-2, logical block 1268624, lost async page write
[14706.079369] XFS (dm-2): metadata I/O error: block 0x9694c78 ("xfs_buf_iodone_callback_error") error 5 numblks 8
[14858.217013] buffer_io_error: 3198 callbacks suppressed
[14858.217051] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 978837, lost async page write
[14858.217058] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 978838, lost async page write
[14858.217061] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 978839, lost async page write
[14858.217064] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 978840, lost async page write
[14858.217066] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 978841, lost async page write
[14858.217069] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 978842, lost async page write
[14858.217072] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 978843, lost async page write
[14858.217075] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 978844, lost async page write
[14858.217080] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 978845, lost async page write
[14858.217083] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 978846, lost async page write
```

is that errors are related to disks ? or file-system or memory cards ?

any advice how to continue from this situation to solution ?